# Ranking rows using SQL Server Rank function without skipping a rank number

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

I want to rank rows in a table without skipping numbers in the rank.  Please see below example.

```
CREATE TABLE #test(
apples int NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into #test( apples ) values ( 10 )
insert into #test( apples ) values ( 10 )
insert into #test( apples ) values ( 20 )
insert into #test( apples ) values ( 30 )

select *, RANK() over (order by apples) as theRank from #test

drop table #test
go
```

The result is

```
apples   theRank
10       1
10       1
20       3
30       4
```

How can I get the rank to not skip the number 2, so that the result looks like

```
apples   theRank
10       1
10       1
20       2<--
30       3<--
```

I don't have to use the Rank function, as long as I get the desired ordering.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try using [DENSE_RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of RANK

```
select *, DENSE_RANK() over (order by apples) as theRank from #test
```

Comment: Exact same answer to the T even spelling and punctuation.  I'll delete my answer because it looks like a copy and paste of yours and you beat me by 2 mins.